# I have two web applications in my tomcat. Both applications are talking to same database

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat6

I have two web applications in my tomcat. Both applications are talking to same database.
Database connection properties are configured in web.xml

1. app1/WEB-INF/web.xml
2. app2/WEB-INF/web.xml

Every time I changed in two places. How to avoid situation?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure JNDI datasource in TOMCAT

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

This will help you to make better deployments in test/dev and prod environments.

Comment: thks.my database is postgres and i using pgpool(connection pooling). so i don't want another pooling layer.

Comment: datasource return connection. already i have used connection wrapper in my project. actually needed configuration variables and values in both application.

Answer (score 0):

which server r u using? try putting file having database configuration in configuration folder of your server and fetch it using jndi-lookup.

Comment: server is tomcat.6.0.10. database is postgres and using pgpool(connection pooling). so i don't want another pooling layer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this build-time solution:
in your web-xml files put templates instead of the actual values. For example `%DB_HOST%` instead of `my.db.server.com`.
In build time replace the templates located in all the relevant files with the actual value (located in some global configuration file, for example).

If you have an ANT-based build solution, you can use the [replace task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) 
to achieve this.